# No viable overloaded operator[] for type

Tags: c++

I have defined a type:

```
typedef unordered_map<string, list<string>> Graph;
```

I have a key:

```
string v = "A12";
```

When I try to access the list using the key:

```
for (auto w = g[v].begin(); w != g[v].end(); w++)
    {

        ...
    }
```

g is type `Graph`, I get the error:

```
No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const Graph'
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::string>` instead. `std::list` doesn't provide arbitrary inexed acces.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am not trying to using the index operator on a the list, I am using it on the map

Comment: `g` is `const` in the context you're using it. Make it not `const`. If you're using C++11 and beyond, use `at` instead of the indexing operator.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is that `g` is a `const graph&`. The indexing operator `[]` may need to create a new element for the map thus mutating it. That's why you cannot use it on a `const graph&` (the problem is `const`).

You can use `g.at(key)` instead that throws an exception if the key is not present.

Comment: So would the best way be to this?
```list<string> theList;
try {
    adjList = g.at(v);
} catch (int e) {
    cout << e << endl;
}
```

Comment: @Bob, I recommend using `auto iter = g.find(v); if ( iter != g.end() ) { ... }`.

Comment: ```auto iter = g.find(v);
        if (iter != g.end()) {
            list<string> adjList = g.at(v);
        }```
@RSahu

Comment: @Bob, You can use `list<string> adjList = iter->second;`. No need to use `g.at(v)` since that requires another search.

Comment: @RSahu Okay, that makes sense. Only problem now is its giving me an error `No viable conversion from 'const value_type'`

Comment: @Bob, I needed to edit my comment. The first version was not right. Take a look again.

Comment: The mutating indexing operator of map allows some really "neat tricks", but (in my view) it was one of the biggest blunders of the C++ standardization.